# Problems with deploying war on openshift

Tags: java, spring, git, maven

I'm trying to deploy my war file of my Java Spring Application to openshift. 
I'm trying to do this with git.

My pom file is build succesfully but my ROOT.war is not deployed...
In Filezilla I can see that my war is in the webapps folder but when I'm trying to reach my website I got a 404 error.

**UPDATE:**
I've added my project structure to my question. In filezilla I saw that there is a ROOT.war file deployed but this is empty....

[Click here to see project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ubcM.png)

Attached you can find my pom:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SussolWebservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>SussolWebservice</artifactId>
  <version>ROOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>
  <dependencies>

      <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.12</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

   <!-- Spring dependencies -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
  
   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
      <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
         <groupId>weka</groupId>
         <artifactId>weka</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\weka.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>opencsv</groupId>
         <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\opencsv-3.7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>log</groupId>
         <artifactId>log</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>loggger</groupId>
         <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>packagemgr</groupId>
         <artifactId>packagemgr</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\packageManager.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>SOM</groupId>
         <artifactId>SOM</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\SelfOrganizingMap.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
   <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to add `<outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>` to the `configuration`  element of `maven-war-plugin`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this didn't solved my problem. I've added my project structure to my question. In filezilla I saw that there is a ROOT.war file deployed but this is empty....